# Sharepoint Web Parts roll up

Tags: sharepoint

I'm pretty new to Sharepoint, but my company wants me to set up a Sharepoint to manage discussions, documents and tasks.
The company has two different departments, so I made one main site and two subsites, one for each department.

On each subsite I have a discussion board. I'm trying to show the "hottest" discussions from each board on the main site. What is the best way to do this?

(I'm using Sharepoint Online)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is using a SharePoint content search webpart. To get your head around the basics of how to pull search results from multiple sites see [SharePoint 2013 Search: My Open Tasks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KdB6jD23jE)

Comment: I thought content search was the way to go, but it looked quite complex. Guess there is no easier way. Thanks for the answer! :)